# Wireless alternative to Logitech G502 Mouse

Tags: wireless, mice

I am looking for an alternative for the wireless Logitech G502. I have the cable version and love it. But the currently available wireless version is just too expensive at about 149€. The cable version was about 50€ when I bought it.

These are the features I am looking for, sorted by importance:

1. ability to unlock the mouse wheel for seamless scrolling
2. ability to change the mouse resolution (for faster or slower more accurate mouse movement) on the fly
3. about the same size and weight as the cabled G502 (~100-150 grams)

Thanks in advance!